# Прописные и строчные буквы

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Как правильно написать "горбатый "запорожец"? Что тут будет в кавычках, что с большой буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В кавычках будет *«горбатый»*. Слово *«запорожец»* в бытовом употреблении (а здесь, судя по эпитету, употребление именно бытовое, разговорное) не закавычивают. А прописные буквы здесь не требуются вовсе. Верное написание: *«горбатый» запорожец.*